# Why doesn't the anticommutator $\{x,p_x\}$ have an unique value?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, anticommutator

The commutator of position and momentum, $[x,p_x]$, has a unique value given by $i\hbar$. Why doesn't the anticommutator $\{x,p_x\}$ also have a definite value?

Comment: Why do you expect it to have a unique value in a theory where the commutator has a unique value? As you already seem to realize the commutator doesn't determine the anticommutator and vice-versa.

Comment: So the anti commutator can have any value?

Comment: You should be more precise than just saying "any value". I think you mean to say it is not a constant operator (i.e. not proportional to the identity)

Comment: You see, it is a bit problematic to say that the anticommutator can have any _value_. It is an operator. It would have certain eigenvalues and a certain expectation value in a given state. You can talk about the value of the operator itself if it can only have one eigenvalue and all states are its eigenstates with this eigenvalue, i.e., when the operator is proportional to identity, e.g., the commutator.

Comment: @AaronStevens I meant to ask whether the operator itself is unique.

Comment: It is still confusing. Unique with respect to what? Using that idea this means the position operator is not unique as well, which is somewhat confusing terminology to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both the commutator and anticommutator have unique values, then by linearity, that would imply that $\hat{x}\hat{p}$ has a unique value. This would be inconsistent with the fact that the matrix element $\langle x |\hat{x}\hat{p}| p\rangle= xp\langle x | p\rangle$ depend on the bra $\langle x |$ and the ket $| p\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

A consistent (and physically relevant) quantum theory can either postulate the commutator of $\hat x$ and $\hat p$ or their anticommutator. Since $\{\hat x,\hat p\}=[\hat x,\hat p]+2\hat p\hat x$, if a quantum theory was to postulate both the commutator and the anticommutator to be certain constant values, it would imply a constant value for the operator $\hat p\hat x$ (and thus, for the operator $\hat x \hat p$) as well.

This would be utterly problematic for the following reason: Let's say $|p\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $\hat p$. Then, $\hat x\hat p|p\rangle=p\hat x|p\rangle$. But now, if $\hat x\hat p$ has to have a constant value, it would mean that each $|p\rangle $ would have to be an eigenstate of $\hat x$ as well. This would further mean that the commutator $[\hat x,\hat p]$ actually vanishes. And since, furthermore, $\hat x\hat p$ has a constant value, $\hat x$ and $\hat p$ will share all the eigenstates. This stands in as much contradiction to the spirit of a theory that we (should) set out to construct.

Thus, in order to construct a quantum theory of physically relevant operators, we postulate the commutator $[\hat x,\hat p]$ to have a constant value and let the expectation value of the anticommutator depend on the state.

Answer (score 1):

If both the commutator $[x,p_x]$ and the anticommutator $\{x,p_x\}$ had constant values, then $x p_x$ and $p_x x$ would also have constant values. This would be bizarre since these values should depend on the detailed dynamics of the system. There is no reason to expect the momentum operator to be inversely related to the position operator for every system.